# What happens if you use high temperature PTFE tape with the heater block?

Tags: hotend

High temperature PTFE tape is rated up to 550°F, which is 288°C.  I'm wondering if it would be useful for components on the hot end to prevent oozing.  Has anyone tried it?

Comment: How would that help fighting oozing, please explain. E.g. when parking the hotend I want it to touch the tape.

Comment: might you have a leaky hotend? also "Does anyone" is not a good format generally... ´

Comment: @Trish: It would probably be more useful putting new parts together.  Teflon has low friction and allows the threads to slide tighter besides sealing gaps in the threads.  The tape layer would be best thin.  Once plastic gets in the threads, things are difficult.  It's easy to twist parts into if we tighten them too tight.

Comment: I've used a M6 tap to clear plastic out of the threads on the heater block.  Some printers use M7.

Comment: @PerryWebb To stop plastic getting as far as the threads, the nozzle should be tightened with no filament and the hotend hotter than you will print at. I couldn't find a 3DP.SE Q&A on that, so it would best to find a couple of videos/articles on the subject before doing it.

Comment: What type of hotend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew stated: PTFE tape should not be needed.
Tighten the nozzle with the hotend hotter than you print at and also clean the threads with a tap if you need to.
To answer your question: it would stop leakage from the threads.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is even potentially beneficial depends on the type of hotend you're using. With one like the Ender 3 where the PTFE tube butts all the way against the nozzle, it's not useful, and if it seems useful it means your hotend is misassembled, since filament is never supposed to make contact with the top of the threads.

For an all metal hotend with flaws in the mating surfaces, it's plausible that it might help, but it rather defeats the purpose of having all metal (high temp).